# Simple algorithms for the reciprocal of a power series

Tags: algorithms, power-series

In my research, I have found myself in need of finding the coefficients of the reciprocal of a power series in subexponential time. Are there simple algorithms that run in polynomial time for finding the series expansion of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ when we have $ f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots $ where $a_0 \neq 0$? I only found very clever algorithms that would be very difficult to implement. I am looking for the simplest algorithm to implement that has polynomial time complexity. I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear because the natural algorithm $b_0=\frac1{a_0},\ b_k= -\frac1{a_0}\sum_{m=1}^k a_m b_{k-m}$ seems polynomial.